# Delete post redirect to the post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to, posts

I'm currently trying to delete a post through the link

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy',  post,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

The problem is that when i click on it, instead of destroying the post, it's redirect me to the show view of the post.

Here is my index.html.erb

```
  <table>
<tr>
  <th>titre</th>
  <th>description</th>
</tr>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= post.title %></td>
  <td><%= post.description %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path(post)%> </td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy',  post,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
<br>
```

And here is my controller posts.controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_post, except: [:create, :index, :new]
  def index
   @posts =  Post.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
   @post = Post.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
     redirect_to :action => "index"
  end

  def update
     respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Lime was successfully updated.' }
      else
    format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Vous n'êtes plus un batard"
  end

  private #private has nos end

    #Must be set to update later
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
    end
end
```

Thx for helping

Comment: Do you have `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` included in your `application.js`? And is `application.js` included into `view/layout/application.html.erb`?

Comment: I just add //= require jquery_ujs. It's know deleting correctly thanks dude !

Comment: I've added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` included in your `application.js` And include `application.js` included into `view/layout/application.html.erb`